# Input and output the same line in java

Tags: java

Is there a method in Java to ensure that when a user inputs a value, the subsequent output appears on the same line, directly adjacent to the input prompt, without moving to a new line? In other words, can we achieve a setup where the input and output are displayed on the same line?

Expectations:

```
Factorial of 5: 120
```

Reality:

```
Factorial of 5
: 120
```

Here's the code for reference:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int total = 1;
    int i;
    System.out.print("Factorial of ");
    int input = s.nextInt();
    for (i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
      total *= i;
    }
    System.out.print(": " + total);
  }
}
```

Comment: Next time, please take care to properly format *your* code *yourself*. And as an advice - random number of empty lines between each statement do not magically make the code more readable, quite the contrary in fact.

Comment: Does this answer help with your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64812365/1832954 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you input 5 you press enter therefore the new line;

This code will solve your problem:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int total = 1;
    System.out.print("Factorial of ");
    int input = Integer.valueOf(s.next());
    for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
        total *= i;
    }

    int count = 1;
    System.out.print(String.format("\033[%dA",count)); // Move up
    System.out.print("Factorial of ");
    System.out.print(input);

    System.out.print(": " + total);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

See in your code when u take an input, you automatically have to press enter and that way, you will be shifted to the next line on a console.

So to prevent that I would recommend you take input first and then print the line after all the processing.
for ex: System.out.print("Factorial of " + "" + input + ": " + total);

or you can use
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls"); after taking an input, this will clear your screen.

Let me know if you need more help.